# Events Manager 'Events' Formatting

Tags: css, wordpress, events, styles

I´m trying to customize Events Manager 'Events' widget but without any satisfactory results.

I would like to get something like 'upcoming events' from the demo page (http://demo.wp-events-plugin.com/events/):

[image]

Instead I just got this:

[image]

This is the code I´m using. Any help with de CSS/formating or clue to get the correct css from 'Events Manager'?

```
 <li>
 <div style="float:left; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;"> #_EVENTIMAGE{50,50}
    </div> 
    #_EVENTLINK
    <ul style = "list-style-type: circle;">
    <li>#_EVENTDATES</li>   
    <li>#_EVENTTIMES</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings I use to produce something similar.

**Default event list format header:**

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="events-table" border=1 frame=void rules=rows>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="event-time" width="150">Date and Time</th>
                    <th class="event-description" width="*">Image</th>
                    <th class="event-description" width="*">Event Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

**Default event list format**

```
<tr>
   <td>
            <span class="capitalize">#l</span><br>
             #j <span class="capitalize">#F</span> #Y<br>
            #_EVENTTIMES
        </td>
   <td>#_EVENTIMAGE{100,100}</td>
        <td class="event-description" style="vertical-align:middle">
            #_EVENTLINK
            {has_location}<br/><i>#_LOCATIONNAME, #_LOCATIONTOWN, #_LOCATIONCOUNTRY </i>{/has_location}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**Default event list format footer**

```
</tbody></table>
```

Here's what it produces: https://www.arbolife.com/events-home/